# openmp gives different result from sequential

Tags: fortran, openmp

I am a beginner with openmp. I am trying to parallize a simple loop. But its clearly wrong.
Can anyone kindly help?

```
use omp_lib
implicit none
integer ::n=20,it,j
real(8) :: a=0,b=5,s,func,del,sum1,tnm,x
it=2**(n-2)
tnm=it
del=(b-a)/tnm
x=a+.5*del
sum1=0.0

!$omp parallel do reduction(+:sum1)
do j=1,it
  sum1=sum1+func(x)
!  write(*,*)func(x)
  x=x+del
end do
!$omp end parallel do
s=.5*(s+(b-a)*sum1/tnm)
write(*,*)s,sum1,it,del
end

function func(x)
  real(8)::x
  func=x
end function
```

**EDIT**
Results:

*Parallel run::*

```
$ ifort -openmp trapzd.f90 
$ ./a.out 
  0.976562500000000        102400.000000000           262144
  1.907348632812500E-005
```

*Sequential Run*

```
$ ifort  trapzd.f90 
$ ./a.out 
   6.25000000000000        655360.000000000           262144
  1.907348632812500E-005
```

`s,sum1` is different in this two run

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark : Results appended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see three issues here:

- A missing type declaration for the function `func`
- `s` is used uninitialized
- Race condition for variable `x`

This works for me:

```
program test
  use omp_lib
  implicit none

  integer       :: n=20,it,j
  real(8)       :: a=0,b=5,s,func,del,sum1,tnm,x,x0
  it=2**(n-2)
  tnm=it
  del=(b-a)/tnm
  x=a+.5*del
  sum1=0.0

  x0 = x
  !$omp parallel do reduction(+:sum1)
  do j=1,it
    sum1=sum1+func(x0+j*del)
  !  write(*,*)func(x)
   end do
  !$omp end parallel do

  ! s is uninitialized here - set it to 0
  ! ...probably not what you had in mind
  s = 0.
  s=.5*(s+(b-a)*sum1/tnm)
  write(*,*)s,sum1,it,del

end program

real(8) function func(x)
  real(8)::x
  func=x
end function
```

Compiled with `gfortran`:

```
OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 ./a.out 
   6.2500000000000000        655360.00000000000           262144   1.9073486328125000E-005
OMP_NUM_THREADS=6 ./a.out 
   6.2500000000000000        655360.00000000000           262144   1.9073486328125000E-005
```

Compiled with `ifort`:

```
OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 ./a.out 
   6.25000000000000        655360.000000000           262144  1.907348632812500E-005
OMP_NUM_THREADS=6 ./a.out 
   6.25000000000000        655360.000000000           262144  1.907348632812500E-005
```

Comment: Thanks.
Possibly the line   `sum1=sum1+func(x0+j*del)` did the trick.